# Issue about bypassing Cloudflare turnstile verification

Tags: cloudflare, bypass

I am working with Python and trying to bypass Cloudflare turnstile verification.
I collected the site key and found it solution.
I try to execute the value with `cf-turnstile-response` but it not working.
How can I process it by `turnstile.render`??

I try to inject solution with `cf-turnstile-response`.